# Drop all tables except specific ones

Tags: mysql, regex, grep, sql-drop

I want to drop all tables except few of them. I am using the following command:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pxxx --add-drop-table --no-data database | grep ^DROP | grep -v "^(cache|webform|redirect)([_a-z0-9]?)+$" | mysql -uroot -pxxx database
```

The regex seems to be fine according this http://www.regexr.com/3aa8k, as the tables that I want to skip are cache*,webform*,redirect. But problem is that it drops everything.

Comment: Remove the last `mysql` command together with the pipe in front of it to see what is filtered by `grep`. For some reason, `grep` needs the `|` characters escaped. Also, it's possible that it will interpret `(`, `)` and `+` differently than what you expect. Maybe you can simplify the `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

your regexp is

```
grep -v "^(cache|webform|redirect)([_a-z0-9]?)+$"
```

which is extended format (`|` and `+` aren't allowed in old grep regexp )

try this instead

```
grep -Ev "^(cache|webform|redirect)([_a-z0-9]?)+$"
```

Or it might be possible to escape the  meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` with backslash